# Angular 6 performance issue with large table

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, typescript, dom

I have a problem with Angular 6 performance issue. In the page there is a large table which has 100 rows and each row has 100 columns. Then this page is kind of laggy when I trying to use libraries like ng-select or ng-bootstrap datepicker, etc. **Even if those libraries has no data exchange with the table**. Which means even if the ng-select is just embedded in the HTML and has no data filled, the open and close of the ng-select drop down is laggy, takes about 0.5 sec to load. Same with other libraries. When I reduce the table to 10 rows, the lagging issue is improved significantly. Why does this happen?

Another observation is that when I use native tags of the HTML such as select option, it is not laggy at all, it react instantly. How to improve the performance in my situation? Thanks!
Code is basically something like this.

app-component:

```
<ng-select></ng-select> 
<row-component *ngFor="let basket of baskets"></row-component>
```

row-component:

```
<div *ngFor="let apple of apples">
    blah blah blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It could also just be an issue of how many DOM elements that are being created and displayed on the page. You could try and use row virtualization which only renders rows that are displayed on the screen.
2. The fact that using ng-select makes the website more laggy than native html tags makes me think that the additional event listeners from the angular components have also decreased the performance of your webpage.

Ag-Grid has a great article about how they optimized displaying entries in a table. https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-performance-hacks/

Answer (score 2):

Do you use any library for the table like Angular Material?
One possible (and very common) solution is virtual scrolling:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling

Comment: I have tried this library. It works fine when you have single list to display. But in my case, I'm having table (2D list) with very large amount of data (around 400+ MBs). And on scrolling, it shows a blank screen first, then load the next data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you may want to consider:

First, do you need to display all 100 columns at once? Is it possible for you to break up the columns into more manageable chunks, and maybe use a tabbed interface (Something like the Angular Bootstrap Tabset https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples) and group related columns into tabs to reduce the amount of columns you have to display on one page.

Second, there will be a performance issue when you get over a certain number of rows, which is where paging the data would be a good option (again, maybe look at Bootstrap paging https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples). You can set a hard limit - maybe 40 rows per page, or set the row limit dynamically by getting the browser window size, subtracting the amount of space you need for menus etc., and dividing the rest by the row height to determine how many rows will fit in the space you have available, and use that as your page size. This way you'll always only have to display a subset of the columns, and only as many rows as will fit on the screen without scrolling, and you should find your performance improves dramatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your advises definitely helps. Paging already exists. Maybe I will try out the tabset or maybe I will furthur reduce the rows in one page.